# CakePHP Pagination sort() on Related Models

Tags: sorting, cakephp, pagination, jquery-ui-sortable, paginator

I have two models: **Plans** and **PlanDetails**.

Relationship is: **PlanDetails** hasMany **Plans**. **Plans** belongTo **PlanDetails**.

In the **PlanDetails** *view.ctp*, I am pulling in related **Plans**.

I am trying to sort the **Plans** by ANY field (I've tried them all), and I cannot get it working. I assume I am overlooking something very simple.

Here is my base code:

PlanDetail >> view.ctp:

```
...foreach ($planDetail['Plan'] as $plan_edit) :
$class = null;
if ($i++ % 2 == 0) {
    $class = ' class="altrow"';
}...

<?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Plan ID', 'Plan.id'); ?>...

...<?php echo $plan_edit['id']; ?>
```

plan_details_controller.php:

```
...function view($id = null) {
    if (!$id) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid plan detail', true));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
    $this->PlanDetail->recursive = 2; // To run the editable form deeper.
    $this->set('planDetail', $this->PlanDetail->read(null, $id));
    $this->set('plan', $this->paginate('Plan'));
}...
```

I should add, no errors are being thrown and the sort() arrows on the ID field are showing as expected, but the sort order DOES not change when clicked either way.

Comment: I think all this should go in your plans_controller. Since you're actually paginating on plans. This might not solve your problem, but it makes sense when you look at the data you're pulling

Comment: @JohnP - You could be right, but I am viewing this all in plan_details view file (using the view action of plan_details controller). And the pagination is called in that file.

Comment: have a look at the SQL dump at the bottom and see if any sorting is done in the SQL and whether it looks weird. It should be doing a simple SELECT *. The issue here is that since you're using the PlanDetail controller, it may be getting confused as to what model it should be sorting

Comment: @JohnP - It is in fact sorting by the SQL "SELECT `Plan`.`id` ... WHERE 1 = 1 ORDER BY `Plan`.`id` asc " and changes to "..desc" if I switch the sort.

Comment: It SEEMS as though the query is taking place as expected, but its not being reflected in the view table.

Comment: hmm, just on the off chance, move the the method to your plans_controller and see if that helps.

Comment: No dice. Did not change anything. Hmmm..

Comment: Let's break it down. Set your recursion level to 0. and simply call `->paginate();` no args. If that doesn't work, you've got some errant bit of code that's misbehaving

Comment: OK will try that. As a side note, my url is also reading right: "plan_details/view/85/page:1/sort:Plan.id/direction:desc"

Comment: Ok as expected, because the recursion is 0, I get this: SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'Plan.id' in 'order clause'. I added  $this->set('plan', $this->paginate()); as well. Same error.

Comment: That can't be. If you're paginating from plans_controller, you shouldn't be getting that. Make sure you move the code back to plans_controller

Comment: I am only attempting all of this in the plan_details_controller. I can't see how it would work through the plans_controller as I am using the plan_details view.ctp.

Comment: just copy that file over. It's easier to get a working point and then change one item at a time to see what breaks it.

Comment: Just out of curiosity if you add
$this->paginate = array('Plan'=>array('order'=>array('Plan.id'=>'desc')));
Just before you set the variable plan what do you get?

Comment: @Leo - doesn't bite with that either... Hmmm.. I have been running tests all day trying to get it working. No luck as of yet. Open to any other ideas!

Comment: Not sure what to do next. I've tried everything I can possibly think of and then some. Wasted a ton of time. And at my limit. What could I be missing here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did to solve this. Based on some helpful direction from johnp & tokes.

plan_details/view.ctp:

```
...$i = 0;
foreach ($plan as $plan_edit) : // note $plan here.
}...
```

In my plan_details_controller.php view action:

```
$conditions = array("Plan.plan_detail_id" => "$id");
$this->set('plan', $this->paginate('Plan', $conditions)); // note "plan" in the first argument of set (this is required to pass the results back to the view). Also. The $condition is set to return ONLY plans that match the plan_detail_id of id (on the plan_details table).
```

And in my view, in order to get my results (because I changed the array name), I had to change the way I was getting the values to:

```
$plan_edit['Plan']['modified'] // note I placed ['Plan'] in front of these calls as the array called for this to get the data...
```

Well until the next problem! SOLVED.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I'm not able to comment on the question itself, but I've noticed that in your action, you set `planDetail` to be the PlanDetail record you read (with `recursive` set to 2), and then you set `plan` to be the result of the `paginate` call.

Then, in your view template, you're iterating over `$planDetail`'s contained `Plan` association, like this:

```
foreach ($planDetail['Plan'] as $plan_edit):
```

But in order to get the sorting and pagination done, you need to be displaying the results of the `paginate` call i.e. iterate over the records contained in `$plan`.

Do a `debug($plan)` in your view template to see what results you get there and to see if the records' ordering changes when you sort by different fields.

Also, perhaps you're using syntax I'm not aware of, but if you simply call `$this->paginate('Plan')` in your controller, I don't know that you're going to get only the related `Plan` records for your particular `PlanDetail` record. (There's nothing tying the `$id` passed into your `view` action with the `Plan` records.) You might need to add some conditions to the `paginate` call, like so:

```
$this->paginate['Plan'] = array('conditions' => array('Plan.plan_detail_id' => $id));
$this->set('plans', $this->paginate('Plan'));
```

Comment: thanks for your comments. You sent me in the right direction. I am going to post my final solution below which seems to be working as expected now.